# Custom keys in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

What I want to achieve is the same as we do when we work with `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`'s method `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` wherein we can access the `info` dictionary as

> info[.originalImage]

What I'm currently doing is this

```
struct Foo {
    var meta: [DictionaryKeys: Any]? = nil

    struct DictionaryKeys: Hashable {
        static let key1: DictionaryKeys // Error Here! I don't know what to put here
    }
}
```

which results in the following error

> 'static var' declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier

and how I finally want to access it is as such

```
let fooObject = Foo()
fooObject.meta[.key1] = "Some value"
```

And access in the same way

Answer (score 2):

the only thing you need to do is create enums. here is the code

```
let fooObject = Foo()
fooObject.meta![.key1] = "Some Value"

struct Foo {
    var meta: [DictionaryKeys: Any]? = nil

    enum DictionaryKeys : String {
        case key1
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont need to provide raw values in case of String. Swift will automatically create one from the case name.